# Figure with tikz composed by a graph and other object

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I drawn a graph with tiKz package.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,>=stealth',initial text=,
every state/.style={draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20},
accepting/.style=accepting by arrow]
\node[state] (E) {$E$};
\node[state] (A) [above right=of E] {$A$};
\node[state] (B) [below=of A] {$B$};
\node[state] (C) [below=of B] {$C$};
\node[state] (D) [below=of C] {$D$};
\path[->] (E) edge node [left] {\textit{label one}} (A);
\path[->] (B) edge node [right] {\textit{label two}} (A);
\path[->] (C) edge node [right] {\textit{label three}} (B);
\path[->] (D) edge node [right] {\textit{other label}} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would insert four rectangles with a text inside aligned with the four nodes of the graph.
Do you know how can I do?

**Edit:**
Sorry, I was not precise in my question before. I would insert rectangles with text aligned with the nodes in this way (I drew it with MS power point).

[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,
                chains,
                positioning,
                }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                 > = stealth',
         shorten > = 1pt,
     node distance = 13mm and 0mm,% deleted "on grid" 
             auto,% added
      start chain = 1 going below,
      start chain = 2 going right,
every label/.style = {font=\small, align=left},% added
every state/.style = {draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20,
                      on chain=1},%node contents={$#1$},
%    initial text=,
%  accepting/.style = accepting by arrow
          X/.style = {rectangle, draw=#1, fill=#1!30, on chain=2}
                        ]
\node (A) [state] {$A$};
\node (B) [state] {$B$};
\node (C) [state] {$C$};
\node (D) [state] {$D$};
\node (E) [state,below left=20mm and 20 mm of A] {$E$};
    \begin{scope}[font=\itshape]
\path[swap,->]
            (D) edge node  {label two}   (C)
            (C) edge node  {label three} (B)
            (B) edge node  {other label} (A);
\draw[->]   (E) edge node  {label one}   (A);
    \end{scope}
%
\node [X=blue,right=11mm of A] {Text};
\node [X=green]   {Relative to};
\node [X=red]     {A};
%
\node [X=blue,right=11mm of B]     {Text};
\node [X=green]   {Relative to node B};
%
\node [X=blue,right=11mm of C]     {Text};
\node [X=green]   {Relative to node C};
%
\node (d1) [X=blue,right=11mm of D]     {Text};
\node (d2) [X=green,right=of d1.east]         {Relative to node D};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With option `auto` the edge labels are better positioned. To be on the right side, I add to first path (for arrows between states D, C, B, A) option `swap` which move labels on the desired side (without this they will be on the left side).

[image]

**Edit:** I slightly improve (my opinion ...) with omitting option `on grid`. This allows me to use `chains` library also for nodes right of state nodes. By this code become quite shorter. Also adding more node in comments is now more simple.